# How to disable "smart stuff" in Ruby plugin for intellij idea

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, rake

I use Ruby and Rake for a number of things.

I have tried using the Ruby plugin for intellij mainly for the block comment '#' insertion and syntax highlighting.  But it does way TOO much "fancy smart stuff" auto complete etc etc etc which I find distracting and confusing as I switch editors, IDEs, and languages ( inconsistencies and differences )

How to I disable all the "fancy smart stuff" other than comment blocks, and syntax highlighting and only enable things like symbol suggestion bit by bit if I ever want to ?

The most annoying ones are the quote insertion when typing a quote and the same for other block enclosures "[" "(" and "{"

Having been around as long as I have I have a muscle memory for inserting the closing delimiter after the string or block and I am constantly having to review things for inserted quotes and missing quotes ( because backspace the deletes a qoute deletes one immediately preceding )  I want all the editors I use to act pretty much the same way.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is it that you want to disable in addition to auto complete?

Comment: You can disable 'Show suggestions as you type' in Preferences/Settings | Editor | General | Code Completion

Comment: moified question see above :)

Answer (score 1):

You can disable automatic completion in Settings. Go to **Editor | General | Smart Keys**. There are many options you can disable:

- Insert pair brackets (), [], {}, <>
- Insert pair quote
- Insert pair %> on Enter in JSP
- Insert pair '}' on Enter
  and so on.

Also there a settings specific for languages. For example, go to **Editor | General | Smart Keys | HTML/CSS** to change automatic completion behavior for XML tags.

Source: [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/completing-punctuation.html).

Comment: sounds good, will try  - I am forever finding myself contorting to delete added "})> as I often type a string or paste a string and go to add a " at the beginning and have to deal with undoing the "" and getting back to "  then going to the end to add a " , and have a muscle twitch memory to do "content" and end up getting "content"" etc.